# Is there any way i can create SQL connection string without passing password

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi I'm new to this and want to know if i can create a connection without passing password in connection string.

I can't use windows authentication because most of users don't have access to database.

```
$ConnectionString="Data Source=$SqlServer;Initial Catalog=$Database; Integrated Security=True;"
```

So have to go with SQL Authentication

```
$connString = "Data Source=$SqlServer;Database=$Database;User ID=$SqlAuthLogin;Password=$SqlAuthPw"
```

But not to pass password in connection string . Is it possible by any way.
If not then also let me know.

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: The design looks like a flawed one. If you don't want (why indeed?) give users access to the DB, use a middleware server instead. The proposed solution, using a shared account, removes a crucial part of your audit chain. Or something else, what, depends what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: You keep on asking this same question over and over. I suggest you stick with one question and respond to comments and requests for clarification until you solve it. Don't just ask the same questions over and over

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's already been asked and left dead here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74011697/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-without-passing-credentials-in-connection-string-using?noredirect=1#comment131342728_74011697

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not allow anonymous access.  You can create a SQL user with only read permissions to information that you want.  The only risk there is that a user could change the password but for a small internal project the risk would probably be acceptable.